# Pantheon Files ignores higher group-permissions

Tags: pantheon-files, release-hera

since eOS 5.1 is fast as hell, I finally use it as my main OS.

But: when ever I mount my home server, I cannot manipulate files on its external HDD.

Problem: all files on my NTFS-formatted HDD are owned by "www-data", and have the group "exthdrw", which I am member of. All files have permissions 460, so I can read/write files via my group membership.

But Pantheon Files ignores tgat. I cannot copy files onto the external server HDD.

It works in Caja (MATE) and Nautilus (GNOME).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a chmod -R 775 on the entire directory. If that'd even work, I'm unsure. Theory suggests so though

ref: https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-recursive/

Comment: That would be too easy. But I chose these permissions for security reasons. I want www-data to read only, but I want multiple users to read/write files, as the server's HDD holds shared data of multiple users.
Is there a way to bypass Pantheon Files' permission check?

Comment: Please raise an issue at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues. Files uses gvfs and other system level utilities to read and write files so it is not clear whether it is a Files problem, but I guess if Nautilus works on the same system then so should Files.